# How to call parallel request in flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using `BLoC` in `flutter`.

As soon as BLoC instance is created I want to make to API calls. To achieve that, I have added the following code inside the constructor.

```
 class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyBlocEvent, MyBlocState> {

    MyBloc() {
        _repository = MyAccountRepository();
        _myAccountList = List();
        add(API1CallEevent());
        add(API2CallEevent());
      }
...
```

and the event handling part

```
...  
     @override
      Stream<MyBlocState> mapEventToState(MyBlocEvent event) async* {
        if (event is API1CallEevent) {
    
       var ap1 =
              await _repository.getAPI1();
         ----
         ----
        }else if (event is API2CallEevent) {
    
      var api2 =
              await _repository.getAPI2();
       ----
       ---
        }
    
    }
```

**The problem I am facing is that the API calls are not executed parallel, which means after `API1CallEvent` is completed then `API2CallEvent` get executed...**

is there any way to do that in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, doing two API calls in parallel and expecting result at the same time is not much related to BLoC.
It is better if each bloc-event triggers a specific set of actions, and events are decoupled from each other.

Additionally;
Instead of raising an event inside init block, it is better to do that when you init Bloc inside a provider. See example;

```
BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
  lazy: false,
  create: (context) => AuthBloc(
    userRepository: _userRepository,
    )..add(AppStartedEvent()),
  ),
```

This generates an event right after Bloc is initialized.

Comment: ..I also had confusion about ..why repository instance ..is required to pass to bloc constructor instead of creating in in bloc..I seen these type of examples in many places..not understood ..why it's required so.

Comment: actually, you don't have to pass repository via provider, but you do that if it is necessary.  for example, when you want to init repository in `main` and then pass it to related BLoC

Comment: another example, when you want to init repository only once in `main` and then make it usable across many BLoCs.

Comment: Thanks got it...is there any we to call parallel  calls in BLoC....in my case each event has specific use case ..that I want to do once BLoC created.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have an answer about making API calls in parallel. But as I said in the answer, I don't think it is related to BLoC.

Comment: It's related to Bloc ..when we add event to BLoC..that is executing one event at time ...even though it's not API

Answer (score 0):

A [bloc](/questions/tagged/bloc) basically is a state machine. It does not do parallelism, that's not what it's built for. It's sequentially going from one state into another. In doing that, it *can* do things in parallel internally, but it cannot (or should not) take input in parallel.

If you want one event to execute multiple awaitable actions in parallel, you can do that:

```
@override
Stream<MyBlocState> mapEventToState(MyBlocEvent event) async* {
    if (event is CallTheAPIsEvent) {
        final results = await Future.wait([
           _repository.getAPI1(),
           _repository.getAPI2()
        ]);

        // do something with the results 

        yield ApisHaveBeenCalledState();
    }

    // more event handling
}
```